How to resolve Qt Compiler Issue/RESOLVED
I am working with Qt for the first time and created a project with a provided template and already have issues. Something about my compiler needing to have its environment variable reset. I have a Mac M1, and already have the CMake App, Homewbrew and GCC.

It states "Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the fill path"

I also notice when I choose my kits that my Mac has the warning triangle, and says "No compiler in kit", how do we put a compiler in the kit?


I'm completely fresh to this, so please be specific in steps! Thank you! :)
I downloaded the necessary compiler and watched a lot of videos, but none of them addressed the issue I had. My friend suggested going into my .zshrc and writing CXX = gcc, but I'm not even sure how to do that.
I just want to my IDE to be able to find my compiler, Im also still confused on the whole concepts of paths. So in what folder or how is Qt told the path of the compile in order to find it?
EDIT/RESOLVED: Just reinstalled my home-brew and qt all together and it worked!

IDK, but the messages make it pretty clear that it is CMake that needs telling where your compiler is, not QT.

Have you tried the Qt docs ?
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring.html#checking-build-and-run-settings
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html

Since it seems Qt is using CMake to build code, my advice would be to try and compile a one line program using CMake, in other words take Qt out of the equation. If you can do that then it proves that CMake is working and that the issue is with Qt, if you cannot then that tells you that you need to fix whatever issue CMake is having. This is the normal problem solving process when programming. Break down a complex problem to try and isolate where the actual issue is.

And if this all seems a bit too much (you are new after all) then that is a clear indication that you are trying to learn too many different things all at once. Slow down, break down your goal into smaller more achievable steps.

If creator hasn't autodetected your compiler you'll need to go into the kit configuration and manually configure it there
